# Using Node's streaming to process chunks of data, for dummies

Tags: node.js, stream

I've had a little look at the documentation for `fs` and `streaming` in Node but I'm finding it really hard to get my head around / can't find some simple tutorial on getting it set up.

I have a very large XML file, it's 1.25gb, annoyingly huge but it's all I've got to work with. This is how I'd read a smaller file:

```
fs.readFile('./xml/bigxmlfile.xml', function(err,data){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Could not open file " + err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        var json1 = JSON.stringify(result);
        var json = JSON.parse(json1);
        // do some stuff
    });
});
```

But I get buffer errors when I try to do this with such a large file. The XML structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <merchandiser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="merchandiser.xsd">   
   <header>
       // Header stuff
   </header>
   <product>
    // Product info
   </product>
   <product>
    // Product info
   </product>
   <product>
    // Product info
   </product>
   // ... to infinity
```

The `fs` documentation says to do: `fs.createReadStream('sample.txt', {start: 90, end:  99});` but...I have absolutely no idea how to work with this, I'm totally new to streaming.

I want to run a function every time `fs` gets to a new `product`, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The call you are using collects all the data (into the var data) and sends it.  With your huge file that causes problems.

You will need to read the file asynchronously and add a listener for `on('data', doSomething())`.  There you will look for `<product>` tags.  This would likely be done in a SAX-style parser.  Google reveals a sax-js project and there may be more.

Found this blog about using sax-js on large documents, looks like just what you need.
http://blog.lagentz.com/nodejs/nodejs-parsing-and-transforming-large-xml-documents/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('./xml/bigxmlfile.xml');

stream.on('data', function(chunk){ 
    //do something on file data
});

stream.on('end', function(chunk){
    // file have been read over,do something...
});
```

And looking for more information,please read this stream handbook: https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook ,it's awesome.

Comment: But what is `chunk` referring to here? As in the question above, can you suggest a method for making `chunk` == an iteration of `product` within the data stream?

Comment: For instance, when I `console.log(chunk)` in your instance I get `<Buffer 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46 2d 38 22 3f 3e 3c 6d 65 72 63 68 61 6e 64 69 73 65 72 ...>` xinfinity.

Comment: @Jascination The `chunk` here means that you separate file for lots of pieces,and it's encoding for `hex`